# How can I disable automatic copy to new localized fields on first save of an entry?

Tags: entries, localization

Is there any way to stop this? It would be nice to stop this (for my purposes) and then tell the template to fallback to content from a certain locale if the current locale does not have content for a given field.

Essentially, I'm searching for the best way to have fields track the changes of a "default" locale. Currently in Craft content is only tracked on the first save of an entry after adding the locale.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible. However, it would make a great [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/) for a new config setting!